# Add divs to scene with JQuery.throwable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a function with jQuery that adds a div into a parent div consisting of divs with the [JQuery.throwable](https://github.com/benahm/jquery.throwable) physics engine assigned to them.

I've made a `<p>` with the class `.button` having this jQuery code to it:

```
$(".button").click(function () {
$("#wrapper").append('<div class="instrument bass"></div>');
```

I also had to reinitiate the JQuery.Throwable function in order for the new div to be apart of the gravity engine, so the code adding a new div looks like this:

```
$(".button").click(function () {
$("#wrapper").append('<div class="instrument bass"></div>');    
$(".bass").throwable({
          containment:"parent",
          drag:true,
          gravity:{x:0,y:0},
          impulse:{
                   f:52,
                   p:{x:1,y:1}
                  },
          shape:"circle",
          autostart:true,
          bounce:2,
          damping:2,
          areaDetection:[[0,0,300,300]],
          collisionDetection: true
});
```

`#wrapper` is the div that works as a container for the whole scene, covering `100vh` and `100w` of the whole browser window, so the divs that bounces around will not fall out of the container. The elements that are in the container are named with the class `instrument` and they have a variation of colors with the additional classes `bass`, `drums`, `lead` and `chord`.

When clicking on `.button` I want to add a new div with the classes `instrument bass` as shown in the code above. I had some initials problems with the "old" divs falling out of the containment before, but then I added the `#wrapper` and added the `containment: "parent"` option to the different classes through jQuery, and that worked.

The problem now is, if I add several new divs in a row, the collision between all the elements are starting to act strange. It's like if there are invisible boxes or something in the scene that creates this unexpected and spastic collision between all elements. I've tried to add `display:inline-block` to `.instrument` to see if that solved it, but it didn't.

I'm guessing that I've made some mistake in the code that adds a new div. Maybe there's some way to simplify it and get rid of this strange collision going on? I've added a Plunker below. First try to throw around the existing divs to see how it should act, and then add several new divs to see how it behaves.

**Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/89LT1xqJZmLznymNypKL?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Add the button.click event at the beginning of  $(document).ready(function()
hope this will work cause it worked for me.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".button").click(function () {
 $("#wrapper").append('<div class="instrument bass"></div>');
 $(".bass").throwable({
                    containment:"parent",
                    drag:true,
                    gravity:{x:0,y:0},
                    impulse:{
                        f:52,
                        p:{x:1,y:1}
                    },
                    shape:"circle",
                    autostart:true,
                    bounce:2,
                    damping:2,
                    areaDetection:[[0,0,300,300]],
                    collisionDetection: true
                });
});
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I get the same strange behavior in the collisions. One thing I've noticed is that the divs I've already added is pushed a bit when I click the button. Not only the div that I add, but the divs that already has been added (not the ones already existing when loading the page from the beginning). Could there be that some value is added to the new divs on and on, creating a bigger and bigger margin to the divs in some way?

Comment: Maybe the bug is occurring because the reinitialization of the script is just adding new options to the new divs and not overwriting the old ones. Could it be a simpler solution to delete the old options and call the script again or something?